# How to use predicates and mapcan use in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Here is an example the Lispworks.com Hyperspec gives for mapcan:

```
 (mapcan #'(lambda (x) (and (numberp x) (list x)))
      '(a 1 b c 3 4 d 5))
=>  (1 3 4 5)
```

I'm not understanding the reason for the

```
(list x)
```

in the *and* form. Without it only T is returned, but why? Also, why is the #' in front of the lambda form?

Answer (score 1):

`And` returns its last form if all forms are non null, so if the predicate returns true, `x` is appended to the result.

The `#'` in front of `lambda` makes the lambda form a function.  In modern Common Lisp you don't need it since there is the `lambda` macro that expands to the same thing.

Comment: More specifically: if `x` is a number, then `(and (numberp x) (list x))` returns `(list x)` and concatenates that to the list. if `x` is not a number, then `(and (numberp x) (list x))` returns `nil`, and `mapcan` does not append `nil` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

[MAPCAN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm)  function &rest lists+ => concatenated-results

MAPCAN **expects** the argument `function` to return a list. In the example the argument `function` calls `LIST` on a number, thus returns a list with one item, a number. `MAPCAN` combines all the result lists into a single list, then.